# Function call without definition(in header, no dlls or static libs)

Tags: c++, function, embedded, call, motorola

I have a embedded controller code handed over, it has a bunch on .c files and some headers and a lot of associated files for the embedded processor, its a motorola MC9S12DT256 and it uses a not-so-good compiler - Cosmic. i used Visual studio(just a txt editor) for modifying the code and it changes the hex file being burned to the processor.

I got it earlier this week and spent most of my time on it and it worked ok for minor changes (where changin a value in the code and compiling again made the necessary changes) Now i have to make some major changes. The code calls certain functions which are not to be found any where in the all of the .hpp/.h/.cpp i got. there are no associated dlls as well. I tried to find some basic link and put it in a .sln and still most data is not recognized (as in i cant go to declaration of defn). 
So my question is - how to get to the function definiton to where it is called when VS blanks out. Find all references also does no help

Thanks
PM

Comment: What sort of functions (by name if nothing more?)   Perhaps they are helpers from a library packaged with the compiler?  Consider using a recursive search tool to scan your entire installation/build machine for their names.  Ultimately, if you find binary implementations with no source, you might have to make informed guesses and craft new prototypes from those.

Comment: You would almost certainly get a better answer if you mentioned the functions that you cannot find. Have you searched the compiler provided include directories?

Comment: The function is can_init0(), can_init1 (these are particular to the code as it is for a controller are nw library) so i am confident these are not compiler intrinsics. They could exist in a static library, i was thinking one sided with visual studio static lib extensions, where as cosmic most def will have different  extensions. In the make file i have all the header paths included - the reason why the code compiled with previous minor changes and i could program my embedded dev which worked as expected after changes. After scanning through all the previous versions

Answer (score 0):

They may be compiler intrinsics (functions provided by the compiler rather then in a library). But it is not clear how you have determined that they do not exist in a static library or why you think you should be able to see a definition (as opposed to a declaration).

When using Visual Studio as an embedded project IDE, you should create the project as a "makefile project" (even if you don't actually have a makefile), and you need to add all the necessary header paths for your embedded code and the Cosmic compiler standard header folder as include files to the project - VS scans the header files for declarations for Intellisense code completion and browser navigation.